# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor terminating

Tags: java-8, threadpoolexecutor

I have a custom API that uses ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to invokeParallelCalls (jar file with a wrapper over ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ). That jar file compiled in Java 7 and works fine when i use it in a web application running in JDK 1.7. Now i have an an application running in JDK 1.8, when i use this API i see that sometimes the task is going to the finally method before the code in that method is completed.The task is supplied with a class, method and arguments for that method. This method has some 10 line of code with a webservice call something like the "processRequest" method given below. So at one point of time, i see the logs from finally block after the first few lines of code (executes till the webservice call) in that method for all the tasks. Whenever this happens, it is very quick and the turn around time is 5 ms (everytime 5ms). During successful execution it takes more time and i am not concerned about the time. By the way the timeout is 180000L

```
public boolean invokeParallelCalls(List<Task> tasks, long inSeconds){
    if ((null == tasks) || (tasks.isEmpty())) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception");
    }
    boolean taskCompleted = true;
    try
    {
        List<Future<Object>> futureList = 
            getThreadPoolExecutor().invokeAll(tasks, inSeconds, 
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        for (Future<Object> task : futureList) {
            taskCompleted &= task.isDone();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return taskCompleted;
}
```

Method Executed:

```
    public String processRequest(String input) throws CustomException{
     String result = null;
     try{
         line 1;
         line 2;
         result = Webservice call;
         line 3;
         line 4;
     }catch (CustomException t)
     {
      throw t;
      }
      finally{
       logMethodEnd("processRequestCompleted");
      }
      }
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "is going to the finally method?"

BTW: You dont need to iterate over the List<Future> after invokeAll as this method returns the list after all the tasks completed (either succesfully or with an exception)

Comment: Sorry i should have explained clearly.Updated the main contents with more information.

Comment: @Holger from the java-doc of the invoke-all "Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete or the timeout expires, whichever happens first." and the isDone method does not check if it succeed - it just checks if the task is completed either via error or via success – I would assume if the timeout hits they are mark as failed/canceled

Comment: @sycyhy: You should have cited the other sentence, “*Upon return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled.*”. That’s what I missed, so you were right.

Comment: @Shankar Anand: your `catch (CustomException t) { throw t; }` has no effect. So everything you describe is entirely plausible, if an exception occurred. The code block is exited early, quiet fast if the exception occurs at the beginning and the `finally` block is still executed, as that’s what `finally` is about. You should log the exception or query the `Future` to find out whether an exception occurred. As sycyhy correctly stated, `isDone()` doesn’t care whether an exception or cancellation occurred.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. The issue i am facing is not related to task terminating. It is because the exception was not caught properly. My issue is with Jersey and java 8